# Getting xml data

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

i am  trying to implement factory pattern for getting XML Document from server.
(using javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder)

I have the classes below for now, could you give your opinion ? Does the structure  make sense for this pattern? (I asked the samequestion on codereview but, if havent any feedback yet)

**DocumentGeneratorFactory** (abstract factory)

```
public interface DocumentGeneratorFactory {

    public Document createDocument(String scheme, String authority,
            String path, HashMap<String, String> parameters)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException;    

}
```

**ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory** (Concreate factory)

```
public class ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory implements
        DocumentGeneratorFactory {

    public Document createDocument(String scheme, String authority,
            String path, HashMap<String, String> parameters)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        Uri.Builder uri = new Uri.Builder();
        uri.scheme(scheme);
        uri.authority(authority);
        uri.path(path);

        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> set = parameters.entrySet();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> params : set) {
            uri.appendQueryParameter(params.getKey(), params.getValue());
        }

        URL url = new URL(uri.toString());

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        return doc;
    } 

}
```

**Request** (Abstract Product)

```
public abstract class Request {
    Document doc;
    HashMap<String, String> queryStrings;

    abstract void prepareRequest() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException;  

}
```

**ProductRequest** (Product)

```
public class ProductRequest extends Request{
    ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory DocumentGeneratorFactory;   
    HashMap<String, String> queryStrings;

    public ProductRequest(ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory DocumentGeneratorFactory,HashMap<String, String> queryStrings){

        this.DocumentGeneratorFactory = DocumentGeneratorFactory;
        this.queryStrings = queryStrings;
    }

    @Override
    void prepareRequest() throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        doc = this.DocumentGeneratorFactory.createDocument("http", "ip-address", "default.aspx",this.queryStrings);     
    }

}
```

Comment: In `ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory` I don't see anything specific to Product being done. Can you elaborate what you are trying there?

Comment: There will be different url request. For example i will have a XML data for products, comments,users ... So i thought i should have different Document and to do this. I have created abstract DocumentGeneratorFactory. ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory is creating specific document with its querystrin hashmap. (there will be also VODDocumentGeneratorFactory, CommentDocumentGeneratorFactory  ...)

Comment: Then ProductRequest product will preaper other part of getting XMl Operation. For example, this guy will get data and parse it to an specific Object. But i havent wrote this part yet.  I just wonder about logic ? Or your approach to this structure

Comment: what would be difference in the code if you write `VODDocumentGeneratorFactory`? I am asking because here you are separating the factories and you are using following code `Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));` which is always going to return the object of same type. So all the factories would be generating the objects of same type and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: maybe you should rethink the design

Comment: VODDocumentGeneratorFactory will return Document, too. But it will get different paramaters, and return different Document. Anyway what is your approach to this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20384/discussion-between-narendra-pathai-and-talhakosen)

Comment: Are you sure abstract factory is the way to go here? It looks more like a Builder case. You intent build the same type of object, but with different parameters, if i understand correctly.

Comment: Not sure, but only that paramaters is varying and i think we should keep up with the composition. So we neeed a factory to prepare Document. Do you suggest any other pattern to design it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not make sense as concrete factories must return objects that they have created but you are using inbuilt Java `DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();`, so which will return the same object no matter what.

That would have made sense if `ProductDocumentGeneratorFactory` was in some way returning the object of type `ProductDocument`.

[Example of Abstract Factory Pattern](http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/abstract-factory-pattern/)

So in your case I don`t think this pattern is making sense.

Comment: Do you have any idea about implementing factory pattern to this ?

Comment: If you will dig down in JDK class `AbstractDOMParser`, you will find a method called `getDocument()` which itself acts as a factory for all different kinds of Documents that are possible. So from your requirement perspective, this pattern is not applicable. But can you share full requirements in some way? I surely wanna help if I totally understand requirement.

Comment: ok you send me empty message to talhakosen@hotmail.com, i ll write back to you

Comment: If you think logically you can call yourself a factory if you have access to creating the objects or produce them in some way.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory
{
     public abstract Product createProduct();
     public abstract Comment createComment();
     public abstract User createUser();

    public Document createDocument(String scheme, String authority,
            String path, HashMap<String, String> parameters)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

//---------Your code -----

        return doc;
    } 


}

public class XMLFactory implements AbstractFactory
{
        public Product createProduct()
          {
              /* use createDocument() */
          }

        //Remaining Code for other stuff u want to create...
}

public interface Product{
 //product

}

public class ProductImpl implements Product
{
//implementation

}
```